Trying to understand the high level handshaking between a Dicord Bot and Python Script
I am not trying get specific code, yet, for my Python script. I am trying to understand the high level handshaking that takes place between Discord Bot and the Python script I am running on my computer. I am aware that I need to add the private token to the script, the unique token that identifies my Bot.
I have the Bot created and recognized by my test Discord server, and the bones of a Python script running in PyCharm.
But I am totally clueless on HOW the Bot will call and interface with the Script. I have Googled "Discord Python handshaking", and have not found anything that is simple to understand.
Any help or directing me to a good link would be appreciated.
